# Assigning an already existing variable to another variable of a different type

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, int

I am currently stuck at a point in a program I have been working on: assigning an already existing variable to another variable of a different type. In my case, it would be int to ArrayList. For example:

```
     int x = 3;
         String string = "Bla Bla Bla";
         List<String> myList = new LinkedList<String>(myList.asList(string.split(" "));

            if(something){
            //Delete x, and assign that same variable name (x) to myList so that myList is called x
}
```

P.S.: I am a very beginner to programming in Java, so please excuse my lack of knowledge on the matter! ;-)

**UPDATE**
For those those who wanted to know why a needed to do this, here is a snipet of my code.

```
                else if(second == rating20 ||
                        fourth == rating20){
                    List<String> player20List = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(player1.split(" ")));
                    System.out.println(player20List);
                    int counter[] = {0,1,2,3};
                    for (int j = counter.length-1; j >= 0; j--){
                        player20List.remove(counter[j]);
                        //TODO Delete contents of second and fourth, and reassign as player20List
              }     
         }   
            List<String> fusedPlayer1 = new ArrayList<String>(first);
            fusedPlayer1.addAll(fourth);

            List<String> fusedPlayer1 = new ArrayList<String>(second);
            fusedPlayer1.addAll(third);
```

It is not shown in the snipet, but `first`, `second`, `third` and `fourth` aswell as `rating20` are ints.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
My program is a first attempt at a genetic algorithm based sentence generator.
[Here](http://www.mediafire.com/view/vbiyhpy3r4zt1ga/Code.txt) is my entire program, and, yes, I am aware that it is very sloppy.

Comment: as far as I know, you can't.  Besides, it would be difficult to read, as your variable names keep changing meaning.  The only language I know of that allows this is various flavors of VB.  Short answer: what you're trying to do is a bad idea.  Don't do it.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? Variable names don't mean what you think they do and *almost* don't exist in compiled code. Instead it's all about references as they are what truly matters. More importantly, your question smells of being an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your edit and new code, but it has a bad code smell to it. I now suspect even more strongly that yours is an XY problem that you may need to fundamentally restructure your program. How? I've no idea given the small bits of information and code snippets were seeing. If you need more help, consider posting a lot more information about your classes.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply illegal in Java : no hidden variables. In languages that allow it (C/C++ for example), it is considered as a bad practice, so why would you want to do so ?